# How to change font size after using scale_fill_discrete() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working the following R code. However, once that I use scale_fill_discrete() to modify the labels in the legend, I can't find the way to modify the font size of the labels in the legend (in other words, the fonts in the legend). What can I do to achieve this?

```
exp<-structure(list(year = c(1985L, 1995L, 2005L, 2020L, 2022L, 1985L, 
    1995L, 2005L, 2020L, 2022L, 1985L, 1995L, 2005L, 2020L, 2022L, 
    1985L, 1995L, 2005L, 2020L, 2022L, 1985L, 1995L, 2005L, 2020L, 
    2022L, 1985L, 1995L, 2005L, 2020L, 2022L, 1985L, 1995L, 2005L, 
    2020L, 2022L, 1985L, 1995L, 2005L, 2020L, 2022L), item = c("Social.security", 
    "Social.security", "Social.security", "Social.security", "Social.security", 
    "Culture..education.and.science.promotion.", "Culture..education.and.science.promotion.", 
    "Culture..education.and.science.promotion.", "Culture..education.and.science.promotion.", 
    "Culture..education.and.science.promotion.", "Bond.expenditure", 
    "Bond.expenditure", "Bond.expenditure", "Bond.expenditure", "Bond.expenditure", 
    "Grants.of.local.allocation.tax", "Grants.of.local.allocation.tax", 
    "Grants.of.local.allocation.tax", "Grants.of.local.allocation.tax", 
    "Grants.of.local.allocation.tax", "Public.works", "Public.works", 
    "Public.works", "Public.works", "Public.works", "Measures.to.secure.food", 
    "Measures.to.secure.food", "Measures.to.secure.food", "Measures.to.secure.food", 
    "Measures.to.secure.food", "Sundry.expenses", "Sundry.expenses", 
    "Sundry.expenses", "Sundry.expenses", "Sundry.expenses", "Other", 
    "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other"), datos = c(9831L, 14548L, 
    20823L, 42998L, 36274L, 4904L, 6802L, 5779L, 9194L, 5390L, 10181L, 
    12857L, 19620L, 22326L, 24339L, 9690L, 12302L, 15923L, 16031L, 
    15656L, 6922L, 14216L, 8015L, 2241L, 1397L, 695L, 272L, 671L, 
    1498L, 1270L, 4347L, 6149L, 5382L, 23190L, 5835L, 6653L, 10888L, 
    10492L, 30119L, 17435L)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = "data.frame")
expenditure <- ggplot(data=exp, aes(x=as.factor(year), y=datos, fill=item)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("Bond expenditure", "Culture, education and science", "Grants of local allocation tax","Measures to secure food","Other","Public works","Social security","Sundry expenses")) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +scale_color_discrete(name="") + 
  ylab("billions of yen") + xlab("") + guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL)) +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(color="black", size=18, face="bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(color="black", size=18, face="bold"),
    legend.text = element_text(size =18), 
    plot.margin = margin(1, 2, 1, 1, "cm"),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill='transparent'),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill='transparent', color=NA),
    rect = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
    axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 18, colour = "black", face = "bold"),
    legend.position = c(0.2, 0.8)
  )
ggsave('expenditure.png', expenditure, bg='transparent', width = 13, height = 13)
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
library(tidyverse)

exp<-structure(list(year = c(1985L, 1995L, 2005L, 2020L, 2022L, 1985L, 
    1995L, 2005L, 2020L, 2022L, 1985L, 1995L, 2005L, 2020L, 2022L, 
    1985L, 1995L, 2005L, 2020L, 2022L, 1985L, 1995L, 2005L, 2020L, 
    2022L, 1985L, 1995L, 2005L, 2020L, 2022L, 1985L, 1995L, 2005L, 
    2020L, 2022L, 1985L, 1995L, 2005L, 2020L, 2022L), item = c("Social.security", 
    "Social.security", "Social.security", "Social.security", "Social.security", 
    "Culture..education.and.science.promotion.", "Culture..education.and.science.promotion.", 
    "Culture..education.and.science.promotion.", "Culture..education.and.science.promotion.", 
    "Culture..education.and.science.promotion.", "Bond.expenditure", 
    "Bond.expenditure", "Bond.expenditure", "Bond.expenditure", "Bond.expenditure", 
    "Grants.of.local.allocation.tax", "Grants.of.local.allocation.tax", 
    "Grants.of.local.allocation.tax", "Grants.of.local.allocation.tax", 
    "Grants.of.local.allocation.tax", "Public.works", "Public.works", 
    "Public.works", "Public.works", "Public.works", "Measures.to.secure.food", 
    "Measures.to.secure.food", "Measures.to.secure.food", "Measures.to.secure.food", 
    "Measures.to.secure.food", "Sundry.expenses", "Sundry.expenses", 
    "Sundry.expenses", "Sundry.expenses", "Sundry.expenses", "Other", 
    "Other", "Other", "Other", "Other"), datos = c(9831L, 14548L, 
    20823L, 42998L, 36274L, 4904L, 6802L, 5779L, 9194L, 5390L, 10181L, 
    12857L, 19620L, 22326L, 24339L, 9690L, 12302L, 15923L, 16031L, 
    15656L, 6922L, 14216L, 8015L, 2241L, 1397L, 695L, 272L, 671L, 
    1498L, 1270L, 4347L, 6149L, 5382L, 23190L, 5835L, 6653L, 10888L, 
    10492L, 30119L, 17435L)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = "data.frame")


expenditure <- ggplot(data=exp, aes(x=as.factor(year), y=datos, fill=item)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("Bond expenditure", "Culture, education and science", "Grants of local allocation tax","Measures to secure food","Other","Public works","Social security","Sundry expenses")) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +scale_color_discrete(name="") + 
  ylab("billions of yen") + xlab("") +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL)) +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(color="black", size=18, face="bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(color="black", size=18, face="bold"),
    plot.margin = margin(1, 2, 1, 1, "cm"),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill='transparent'),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill='transparent', color=NA),
    rect = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
    axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 18, colour = "black", face = "bold"),
    legend.position = c(0.2, 0.8),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 60)
  )
expenditure
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. However, it is not working. I don't know why

Comment: @Marlom okay, I made it so it is all in one, you don't need anything else. Try running all of the above code now. It should work (fingers crossed!)

Comment: It definitely worked now. Thank you very much! Unfortunately, I can't vote